# GreenDao - determine database size on runtime

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I would like to know please how to get my database(which is off course ***.sqlite file) size in bytes?

My current way to do it(which isn't working) is:
    new File(DataManager.getInstance().db.getPath()).length()

but I'm just getting here the same number every time 53,676~ , which is irrelevant to the database's content, I'm getting this number even when it's empty.

Thank you.

Comment: SQLite might reserve more size than currently necessary. Did you try to insert data that exceeds your current file size?

Comment: yeah off course, and it's size just got bigger and bigger(using the above line of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the solution is pretty simple, my recent way to check the database file was good.
But I didn't take in account that greenDao adds to the database another 53 KB. So an empty DB size would be 53± KB and after some insertions it would get bigger and bigger.